# Custom resolutions

Tags: display, display-resolution, xrandr

I have a Acer E5-571 with a intel i5. My graphic is onboard and I need a resolution bigger that 1366x768. I tried the xrandr but I found a big problem

```
roney@E5-571:~$ xrandr --newmode "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
roney@E5-571:~$ xrandr --addmode eDP1 "1440x900_60.00"

X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  37
  Current serial number in output stream:  38
```

I need help for this problems. Thanks and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Is your first line the result of a call to `cvt`?

Comment: Looking at the web, it seems your laptop does have a 1366x768 display. If you change it with xrandr everything will look blurry and ugly. If you need a bigger resolution buy a new screen really.

Comment: Hi Joakim Koed, I had called cvt. roney@roney-Aspire-E5-571:~$ cvt 1440 900 60
# 1440x900 59.89 Hz (CVT 1.30MA) hsync: 55.93 kHz; pclk: 106.50 MHz
Modeline "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync